Nuxt error in prerendering using netlify provider
When generating my Nuxt3 project I'm receiving the following error from the prerenderer:
ℹ ✓ built in 7.25s                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          12:15:02 PM
✔ Server built in 7259ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    12:15:02 PM
ℹ Initializing prerenderer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            nitro 12:15:02 PM
ℹ Prerendering 8 initial routes with crawler                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          nitro 12:15:05 PM
  ├─ /200.html (139ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 nitro 12:15:05 PM
  ├─ /404.html (141ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 nitro 12:15:05 PM
  ├─ /contact-us (256ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               nitro 12:15:05 PM
  ├─ /_payload.json (3ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              nitro 12:15:05 PM
  ├─ /.netlify/images?url=%2Fimages%2Fbg%2Fpreloader.gif (28ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        nitro 12:15:05 PM
  │ ├── Error: [404] Page not found: /.netlify/images?url=%252Fimages%252Fbg%252Fpreloader.gif
  │ └── Linked from /

I am not familiar with Nuxt and I am unsure where exactly I should look. The gif referenced in the error is in /public/images/bg/ and the documentation confirms that it should be correct. Indeed all images are working fine, except for the preloader.
I take it that the .netlify folder is created on generation because I'm using this provider in nuxt.config.ts:
  image: {
    provider: 'netlify',
    format: ['webp']
  },

The image is referenced in the index in this way: <NuxtImg preload src="/images/bg/preloader.gif" alt="" /> (I tried adding format to specify gif but it has no effect.
Could anyone point me in the right direction to help me understand what I'm doing wrong? Happy to provide any other data that might be needed to pinpoint the issue.

Hey, I am having same issue now, did you manage to get a workaround?
